# How to create and write to file from Jenkin's with Groovy scripting?

Tags: xml, file, jenkins, groovy

I am using Groovy [DSL Build Flow plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin) for running another job with different parameters.

Finally, I am collecting it to XML format:

```
<testsuite tests='1'>
  <testcase name='build_1' build_number='#882'>
    <failure />
  </testcase>
</testsuite>
```

I want to write this XML to file.

I tried

```
def file = new File("report.xml")
file << result
```

where `result` is exactly file content. However, after build is finished I don't see any file.

Here is snippet of code for creating XML file:

```
writer = new StringWriter()
builder = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(writer)

builder.testsuite(tests: builds.size()) {
    for (bld in builds) {
        def buildName = bld.key
        def numberOfBuild = hudson.console.HyperlinkNote.encodeTo("/" + bld.value.getUrl(),
                String.valueOf(bld.value.getDisplayName()))
        def statusOfBuild = hudson.console.HyperlinkNote.encodeTo('/' + bld.value.getUrl()
                + "console", bld.value.result.toString())

        if (statusOfBuild.contains("FAILURE")) {
            testcase(name: "$buildName", build_number: "$numberOfBuild") {
                failure()
            }
        } else {
            testcase(name: "$buildName", build_number: "$numberOfBuild")
        }

        build.setResult(build.result.combine(bld.value.result))
    }
}

println writer.toString()

def file = new File("report.xml")
file << result
```

I couldn't find any reasonable solution for creating file.

***How to create this file exactly at folder for this build?***

Comment: Do you want to use absolute filepath to write the contents?

Comment: @Rao if it helps create file in the build folder, why not.

Comment: Ok, then you may give it try with absolute report file path and see if that resolves.

Comment: Groovy DSL Build Flow has been replaced by Jenkins Pipeline (declarative and scripted pipelines). If you changed to use a pipeline job it has a convenient "writeFile" construct. Something like "writeFile file: 'someFile.txt', text: 'someText". See here: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-writefile-code-write-file-to-workspace

Comment: @macg33zr Sounds cool for creating a new file. However, I have to use Build Flow plugin. And create the file in a workspace is required here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googling and deep debugging I solved this issue:

```
def file = new File(build.workspace.toString() + "/report.xml")
writer = file.newWriter()
builder = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(writer)
// create correct repport file
builder.testsuites() {
    builder.testsuite(name: "tms-edge-load", tests: builds.size()) {
        for (bld in builds) {
            def buildName = bld.key
            def statusOfBuild = hudson.console.HyperlinkNote.encodeTo('/' + bld.value.getUrl()
                    + "console", bld.value.result.toString())
            println statusOfBuild

            if (!statusOfBuild.contains("SUCCESS")) {
                testcase(name: "$buildName") {
                    failure()
                }
            } else {
                testcase(name: "$buildName")
            }
        }
    }
}
println writer.toString()
writer.close()
```

The file is saved successfully to project workspace:

```
<testsuites>
  <testsuite name='tms-edge-load' tests='1'>
    <testcase name='build_1'>
      <failure />
    </testcase>
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Comment: I'm fighting against  a similar problem, Even with your code I always get `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'testcase' found among steps [acceptGitLabMR, addGitLabMRComment, [...]` in my pipeline job

Comment: @RodKimble you have to create your project like `Build flow project`

Comment: my fault. No I am using a plain `pipeline job` sorry for the misunderstanding